# Fixing '/dev/null: Permission denied' repeatedly in chroot

Tags: linux, permissions, chroot

I've chrooted into an external disk with `sudo chroot /mnt/disk`, but almost everything I do (logging in, tab-completion, `less`ing a file, ...) results in an error mentioning `/dev/null: Permission denied`, even if the command seems to work.

/dev/null has the correct permissions (666), and `file` says it's a character device, so it's not like anything has overwritten it with a regular file or changed the permissions.

What can I do to fix this?

Here's what tab-completion (of `ls /u`) results in:

```
$ ls /ubash: /dev/null: Permission denied
bash: _upvars: `-a2': invalid number specifier
bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
bash: _upvars: `-a0': invalid number specifier
```

Answer (score 10):

The disk might be mounted with the `nodev` option, which `mount` interprets thusly:

> Do not interpret character or block special devices on the file system.

You can verify this by checking the output of `mount` *outside* the chroot:

```
$ mount
...
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/disk type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)
```

(This is a particularly tricky problem to spot, as configuration outside of the chroot is affecting the behaviour of programs inside it!)

Fixing it is as easy as remounting without the `nodev` option. The following command will accomplish this (even while the chrooted process is running!), although there's probably a way that removes *just* the `nodev` option without removing all the other options too:

```
sudo mount -o remount /dev/sda1 /mnt/disk
```